# log in with email when I have a facebook account

Tags: support, login

I made my account with facebook.

Is it possible to log in without the facebook option and just using my emailadres and a password?

Would the password be the same as my facebook password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Stack Exchange is using OpenID. This means that you log in only to Facebook with username and password, then Stack Exchange gets a token from Facebook used to identify you.

The only OpenID provider where you type the username (email actually) and password directly when logging in, is the Stack Exchange OpenID provider.

Comment: So because I created my account with Facebook that's the only way to log in with my account? If I understand you correctly

Comment: @Damek - You can _add_ other OpenId providers if you want, through the "my logins" link on your profile. Any OpenId provider associated with your account can be used to log in with.

Comment: @Damek Oded is correct, was going to reply same thing but you deleted your comment for some reason. (you can edit comments, by the way)